# Typescript / Angular2: Cast JSON to interface with Observable & JSONP

Tags: typescript, angular, jsonp, rxjs, observable

I'd like to cast my json-array to my interface which I've created and like to display it in the browser. I think there is probably something wrong with my interface but I can't figure it out... *What do I need to change to get my code running?*

**Interface:**

```
 export interface Video {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import {Video} from './networking/api';

    private videoData: Observable<Video[]>;
    ngOnInit() {
                this.displayNewstVideo(10);
            }

            private displayNewstVideo(count: number) {
                this.videoData = this.jsonp
                .get('localhost:8080/video/newst/' + count + '?jsonp=JSONP_CALLBACK')
                .map(res => (res.json() as Video[]));
                alert(this.videoData.count);
            }
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="video" style="font-family:sans-serif" *ngFor="#entry of videoData | async;  #i = index">
      <br *ngIf="i > 0" />
      <span class="title" style="font-size:1.2rem">
        <span>{{i + 1}}. </span>
        <a href={{entry.urlDesktop}}>{{entry.name}}</a>
      </span>
      <span> ({{entry.description}})</span>
      <div>Submitted at {{entry.createdAt * 1000 | date:"mediumTime"}}.</div>
    </div>
```

**JSON**

```
[{
id: 1,
name: "Some Name",
description: "BlaBla",
createdAt: "2016-05-04 13:30:01.0",
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Some Name",
description: "BlaBla",
createdAt: "2016-05-04 13:30:01.0",
}]
```

**Edits**

1. I've checked if the request is correct in my network-tab in chrome and it is working as excepted: 200 OK --> Response ist also fine
2. I edited my code as Thierry stated out and now it is finally showing the first object in my array :-)!! But I get following error now:

> Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in app/html/app.html:27:11
>       ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: RangeError: Provided date is not in valid range.
>       ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>       RangeError: Provided date is not in valid range.
>           at **boundformat** (native)
>           at Function.DateFormatter.format (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/intl.js:100:26)
>           at DatePipe.transform (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.js:25:37)
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view_utils.js:188:22)
>           at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent1.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.template.js:377:148)
>           at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:200:14)
>           at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:289:44)
>           at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:215:37)
>           at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.template.js:198:8)
>           at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:200:14)
>       ERROR CONTEXT:
>       [object Object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following instead:

```
this.videoData = this.jsonp
    .get('localhost:8080/video/newst/' + count +
                      '?jsonp=JSONP_CALLBACK')
            .map(res => <Video[]>res.json();
```

**Edit**

I think that your request doesn't return JSONP content but classical one (JSON). If so, you could try the following:

```
import { bootstrap }  from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from 'angular2/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  templateUrl: "app.html",
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
class App {
  private feedData: Observable<Video[]>;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayNewstVideo(10);
  }

  private displayNewstVideo(count: number) {
    this.videoData = this.http
      .get('localhost:8080/video/newst/' + count)
      .map(res => (res.json() as Video[]))
      .do(videoData => {
        console.log(videoData);
      });
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tipp - sadly it didn't work ... do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by it doesn't work? ;-) Do you an error? Moreover your alert should be moved into a do operator... In your case are there when it's executed.

Comment: I'd like to parse my json into my interface and for there on I'd like to show the content of my interface in my html. But I do not get any compiler-errors or something. Infact I am a complete new to Typescript and Angular2.

Comment: In fact res.json() will parse the JSON content. Interfaces are only at design time for type checking. They aren't used at runtime. Do you have your data displayed?

Comment: What do you understand whit displayed? My html keeps empty in my browser - no content is shown. Btw I got the idea doing it like this from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-build2016-demos/tree/master/ng-reddit

Comment: Your code looks good. Could you have a look at several things: 1. the Network tab of devtools in your browser to see the request 2. add a `console.log(res.json());` within the map callback to see the content you have here.

Comment: I think that I found your problem. Your request isn't a jsonp-compliant one but a classical one. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: You were right it was a classical request. Now it is finally showing the first object of my array - thank you! But I got new errors now - I would be glad if you could take a look into it. Kind Regards and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a class instead of an interface, so in this case video.model.ts would be:

```
export class Video {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public description: string,
    public createdAt: string){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave a presentation of **TypeScript** recently, this reminded me of what of the slide's titles "There is no interface!" In **TypeScript** when you define an `interface`, it actually compiles down to nothing. Which can be somewhat misleading. I think I understand what you're trying to do though:

The issue is the way that the **JSONP** object comes back, it's padded. So it sits in the index `[1]`. Try this instead:

```
this.videoData = this.jsonp
    .get('localhost:8080/video/newst/' + count +
                      '?jsonp=JSONP_CALLBACK')
            .map(res => <Video[]>res.json()[1]);
```